# Different Results using Parallel foreach everytime Excel Worksheet is read

Tags: vb.net, excel, task-parallel-library, excel-interop, parallel.foreach

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class TestCarDatas
    Public Property RowID As Integer
    Public Property ModelYear As Integer
    Public Property VehMfcName As String
    Public Property EmgVeh As Boolean
End Class

Module ExcelParallelDataGather2
    Public Const ExcelVehDataPath As String = "D:\Users\Dell\Desktop"
    Public rwl As New System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock()
    Public rwl_writes As Integer = 0
    Public FullTestVehData As New List(Of TestCarDatas)()
    Public x1App As New Excel.Application
    Public x1Workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Public x1Worksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Public x1WkshtLrow As Integer

    Sub main()
        x1App.Visible = False
        ErrorNotify = False
        Console.WriteLine("Excel Parallel foreach operation program....")
        Dim cki As ConsoleKeyInfo
        x1Workbook = x1App.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(ExcelVehDataPath, "TestCarDatabase2014.xls"), , True)
        x1Worksheet1 = x1Workbook.Sheets(1)
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Press escape key to exit, 'a' key to reiterate, 'c' key to clear console")
            cki = Console.ReadKey()
            If Chr(cki.Key).ToString = "A" Then
                Console.WriteLine("--> Processing...")
                FullTestVehData.Clear()
                rwl_writes = 0
                Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(11, x1WkshtLrow + 1), _
                Function()
                    ' Initialize the local states 
                    Return New List(Of TestCarDatas)()
                End Function, _
                Function(partrange, loopState, localState)
                    ' Accumulate the thread-local computations in the loop body
                    localState = populateCardata(x1Worksheet1, partrange.Item1, partrange.Item2)
                    Return (localState)
                End Function, _
                Sub(finalstate)
                    ' Combine all local states
                    Try
                        rwl.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite)
                        Try
                            ' It is safe for this thread to read or write
                            ' from the shared resource in this block
                            FullTestVehData.AddRange(finalstate)
                            Interlocked.Increment(rwl_writes)
                        Finally
                            ' Ensure that the lock is released.
                            rwl.ReleaseWriterLock()
                        End Try
                    Catch ex As ApplicationException
                        ' The writer lock request timed out.
                    End Try
                End Sub)
            End If
            If Chr(cki.Key).ToString = "C" Then
                Console.Clear()
                Console.WriteLine("Excel Parallel foreach operation program....")
            End If
            If Chr(cki.Key).ToString <> "A" And Chr(cki.Key).ToString <> "C" And _
               cki.Key <> ConsoleKey.Escape Then
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid response via key press")
            End If
        Loop While (cki.Key <> ConsoleKey.Escape)
    End Sub

    Friend Function populateCardata(ByVal WksheetObj As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rngStart As Integer, _
                                    ByVal rngStop As Integer) As List(Of TestCarDatas)
        Dim wkrng(12) As String
        Dim PartVehData As New List(Of TestCarDatas)
        PartVehData.Clear()
        For i As Integer = rngStart To rngStop - 1
            Dim data As New TestCarDatas
            For j As Integer = 0 To 12
                wkrng(j) = WksheetObj.Cells(i, j + 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            Next
            With data
                .RowID = i
                .ModelYear = WksheetObj.Range(wkrng(0)).Value2
                .VehMfcName = WksheetObj.Range(wkrng(1)).Value2
                If WksheetObj.Range(wkrng(11)).Value2 = "Y" Then
                    .EmgVeh = True
                Else
                    .EmgVeh = False
                End If
            End With
            PartVehData.Add(data)
        Next
        Return PartVehData
    End Function

End Module
```

I am trying to get the Excel Worksheet data using parallel foreach and range Partitioner, creating lists in thread local storage and finally adding them using thread safe methods like synclock or reader-writer locks


Rows from 11 to last row in worksheet are to be read and populated in a List(of T) 

I observe following when I execute above code

1. When rows in worksheet are greater(example >2000), this code works as expected everytime
2. When rows in worksheet are less, this code returns partial list during first few iteration (data from some of the partitioner ranges are lost). If I re-iterate it (pressing key 'a') multiple times, then sometimes it returns expected results (final list count = no. of excel rows required to be read)

Why this phenomenon is observed?

What is the solution using parallel foreach, if I need correct results during first run/iteration irrespective of no. of rows in worksheet?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Tip: to get the best answer, it is good to paste code here but try to reduce it to a minimum example that still shows the problem. The amount of code you pasted is a lot to go through and it might discourage some people to take a look at it.